# GWT - XML parser

Tags: gwt

I am trying to use GWT xml parser but the compiler throws next

> [ERROR] Line 62: No source code is available for type
>   com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?
>            [ERROR] Line 62: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?
>            [ERROR] Line 63: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?
>            [ERROR] Line 65: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?
>            [ERROR] Line 69: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.Node; did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?

I don't get it how to solve the problem because **import** code gives no errors :( Help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems I was to add to my gwt.xml code like a

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML"/>
```

then code compiled :)

I hope this saves one's day